# Why does this C substring method not work?

Tags: c, substring

I have this written so far. substring(orig, 3, 3, substr)
Given:
orig = "onetwothree"
should make 
substr = "two" ,but it doesn't what am I doing wrong?

```
void substring(char* source, int start, int length, char* target) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        target[i] = source[start + i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems You are trying to modify a string literal which gives u a Undefined behavior.

Comment: You should make sure so your buffer has enough space to hold the substring and you should also null terminate it after the loop: `target[length] = 0; `

Comment: @AlokSave no, the string literal is never modified, only read. the target is modified.

Comment: Don't forget to check `if length > string length`. Also you have to check if the target could hold `length` characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to zero-terminalte the target string.

There also a few extra checks you should have implemeneted. For example, what should happen when the source string ends before `length` characters are copied?

Additionally, it makes sense to const-qualify the source pointer (`const char* source`) and use `size_t` instead of `int` to represent indices and lengths.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the null-termination character '\0'.

```
target[length] = '\0';
```